# Scala - Subtracting two natural numbers at the type level

Tags: scala, types, type-level-computation

**We can encode addition and multiplication of natural numbers in Scala. But, is it possible to subtract two natural numbers at the type level?**

I have half-copied the following encoding of natural numbers in Scala:

```
sealed trait  Natural {
  type Plus[That <: Natural] <: Natural
}

case object Zero extends Natural {
  override type Plus[That <: Natural] = That
}

case class Suc[Prev <: Natural](n: Prev) extends Natural {
  override type Plus[That <: Natural] = Suc[Prev#Plus[That]]
}
```

I then added multiplication on my own:

```
sealed trait Natural {
  type Plus[That <: Natural] <: Natural
  type Mult[That <: Natural] <: Natural
}

case object Zero extends Natural {
  override type Plus[That <: Natural] = That
  override type Mult[That <: Natural] = Zero.type
}

case class Suc[Prev <: Natural](n: Prev) extends Natural {
  override type Plus[That <: Natural] = Suc[Prev#Plus[That]]
  override type Mult[That <: Natural] = (Prev#Mult[That])#Plus[That]
}
```

Which seems to be in-line with other implementations I later found, and also work properly:

```
implicitly[Nat5#Mult[Nat2] =:= Nat10]
implicitly[Nat4#Mult[Nat4] =:= Nat8#Mult[Nat2]]
```

For the past hours I have been trying to implement subtraction.
With the following approach, I seem to be able to subtract two numbers correctly, if the one you subtract (`b` in `a - b`) is an odd-number:

```
sealed trait  Natural {
  type Previous <: Natural
  type Minus[That <: Natural] <: Natural
}

case object Zero extends Natural {
  override type Previous = Zero.type
  override type Minus[That <: Natural] = That
}

case class Suc[Prev <: Natural](n: Prev) extends Natural {
  override type Previous = Prev
  override type Minus[That <: Natural] = (That#Previous)#Minus[Prev]
}
```

The above leverages the fact that `(N - M) = (N - 1) - (M - 1)`. Eventually, a recursion step of `M` will hit `Zero.type`, and return the corresponding recursion step of `N`.
Actually, notice that my implementation, at a given step, translates to `(N - M) = (M - 1) - (N - 1)`. Because subtraction is not commutative, this is incorrect; but, because this "swap" occurs at every recursive step it cancels out **if the number being subtracted is odd**. If it is an even number, then this implementation is off by one. In particular, it is one less than the correct number:

```
implicitly[Nat10#Minus[Nat3] =:= Nat7]  // Compiles
implicitly[Nat9#Minus[Nat3] =:= Nat6]   // Compiles
implicitly[Nat8#Minus[Nat3] =:= Nat5]   // Compiles

implicitly[Nat10#Minus[Nat2] =:= Nat8]  // Does not compile, while:
implicitly[Nat10#Minus[Nat2] =:= Nat7]  // Compiles

implicitly[Nat5#Minus[Nat2] =:= Nat3]  // Does not compile, while:
implicitly[Nat5#Minus[Nat2] =:= Nat2]  // Compiles
```

To understand why, give it a try on paper with `m = Suc[Zero.type] (Nat1)` for the odd/correct case, and `m = Suc[Suc[Zero.type]] (Nat2)` for the incorrect scenario. In either case, the number `n` ( as in `n - m` is not important)

Anyway, I do have a feeling that I might be on the right track with this approach but I am stuck.

1. Do you have any idea how to do this ? Maybe you can you point me to an implementation of subtraction at the type level ?
2. Perhaps this can only be achieved by encoding the negative counterpart of the natural numbers ?

p.s. I am not concerned what happens when `m > n` in `n - m`.

**Usefull for trying out the examples on the repl:**

```
type Nat0  = Zero.type  
type Nat1  = Suc[Nat0]  
type Nat2  = Suc[Nat1]  
type Nat3  = Suc[Nat2]  
type Nat4  = Suc[Nat3]  
type Nat5  = Suc[Nat4]  
type Nat6  = Suc[Nat5]  
type Nat7  = Suc[Nat6]  
type Nat8  = Suc[Nat7]  
type Nat9  = Suc[Nat8]  
type Nat10 = Suc[Nat9]  
type Nat11 = Suc[Nat10]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the recursive definition for subtraction matches on the second argument, you can define:

```
sealed trait Natural {
  type ThisType <: Natural  
  type Previous <: Natural
  type Minus[That <: Natural] = That#SubtractThis[ThisType]
  type SubtractThis[That <: Natural] <: Natural
}

case object Zero extends Natural {
  type ThisType = Zero.type
  type Previous = Zero.type
  type SubtractThis[That <: Natural] = That
}

case class Suc[Prev <: Natural](n: Prev) extends Natural {
  type ThisType = Suc[Prev]
  type Previous = Prev
  type SubtractThis[That <: Natural] = Previous#SubtractThis[That#Previous]  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the trouble of answering. I believe however that this answer is incorrect (it was actually my first attempt). Notice that whatever `N` and `M`, the result `N#SubtractThis[M]` will always be `Zero.type`. This is because by using `N-M = (N-1) - (M-1)` directly, the "recursive component" of `M` will reach `Zero.type` and then remain so for further recursive steps. At the same time, the "recursive component" of `N` will continue being decremented until it also reaches `Zero.type`.  (suggestion: try it on paper for `n = Suc[Suc[Suc[Zero.type]]]` and `m = Suc[Zero.type]`)

Comment: "Notice that whatever N and M, the result N#SubtractThis[M] will always be Zero.type". No, it won't. E.g. `N = Nat0` and `M = Nat1` (or anything except `Nat0`). Did you miss that `N#SubtractThis[M]` represents `M-N`, not `N-M`?

Comment: You can see how it works at https://scastie.scala-lang.org/enO8ICfVScm3ljYlE2MfjA.

Comment: Apologies; had missed the `Minus` in `Natural`. Amazing solution. Question answered.